# Making several feeds by using mock data with map in React

Tags: reactjs

Finally, I almost did with Instagram clone. I really appreciate StackOverflow users! For now, I tried to make several feeds(now, I have only one feed). So, I made a `FeedInfo.json` file to get several feeds information.(I made it randomly) and receive this information in the `Feed.js` but I got this error message `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` so I tried to use this one

```
{/* {(this.feedList.map || [])((article, i) => { */}
```

It works but it didn't show anything...
I will leave a code below to help you understand what I said!
[image: Instagram Clone]

This is `FeedInfo.json`

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "id": "test",
    "selfiImg": "selfi-img",
    "feedImg": "ucscPic",
    "describtion": "This is super coooooool!",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "wecode",
        "content": "Welcome to world best coding bootcamp!",
        "isLiked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "joonsikyang",
        "content": "Hi there.",
        "isLiked": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "userName": "jayPark",
        "content": "Hey.",
        "isLiked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "id": "test",
    "selfiImg": "selfi-img",
    "feedImg": "ucscPic",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "wecode",
        "content": "Welcome to world best coding bootcamp!",
        "isLiked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "joonsikyang",
        "content": "Hi there.",
        "isLiked": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "userName": "jayPark",
        "content": "Hey.",
        "isLiked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "id": "test",
    "selfiImg": "selfi-img",
    "feedImg": "ucscPic",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "wecode",
        "content": "Welcome to world best coding bootcamp!",
        "isLiked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "joonsikyang",
        "content": "Hi there.",
        "isLiked": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "userName": "jayPark",
        "content": "Hey.",
        "isLiked": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is `Feed.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';
import {
  FaRegHeart,
  FaRegComment,
  FaRegPaperPlane,
  FaRegBookmark,
  FaEllipsisH,
} from 'react-icons/fa';
import Comment from '../../../compoonents/Comment/Comment';
import selfiImg from '../../../assets/images/about.png';
import ucscPic from '../../../assets/images/ucscPic.png';
import '../../../../../jiwanjeon/FeedInfo.json';

class Feed extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      commentList: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/commentData.json', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          commentList: data,
        });
      });
  }
  getValue = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  addComment = () => {
    this.setState({
      commentList: this.state.commentList.concat([this.state.value]),
      value: '',
    });
  };

  addCommEnter = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.addComment();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="feeds">
        {/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */}
        {/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */}
        {/* {(this.feedList || []).map((article, i) => { */}
        {(this.state.feedList || []).map((article, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="article">
              key = {i}
              <div className="identi">
                {/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */}
                <img
                  className="selfi-identi"
                  alt="selfi-img"
                  src={article[i].selfiImg}
                />
                {/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */}
                <span className="name"> {article[i].id} </span>
                {/* <i id="test" class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i> */}
                <div className="faEllipsisH">
                  {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsisH} /> */}
                  <FaEllipsisH />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="pic">
                {/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */}
                <img id="feed-pic" src={article[i].feedImg} />
              </div>
              <div className="show-box">
                <div className="reaction-icons">
                  <FaRegHeart className="heart" />
                  <FaRegComment className="comment" />
                  <FaRegPaperPlane className="plane" />
                  <FaRegBookmark className="bookMark" />

                  {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="heart" />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} className="comment" />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} className="plane" />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookmark} className="bookMark" /> */}
                </div>

                <div className="like-counts">
                  <span>like 4,000</span>
                </div>

                <div className="check-comments">
                  <span>
                    {/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */}
                    {this.articleicle[i].descirbtion}
                  </span>
                  <a id="space" href="">
                    expanding
                  </a>
                  <br />
                  <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                  <ul className="feed-comments">
                    <Comment commentAddList={this.state.commentList} />
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="comment">
                <i className="fa fa-smile-o" />
                <input
                  // onChange={this.textChange}
                  // onKeyPress={this.enterClick}
                  onKeyPress={this.addCommEnter}
                  onChange={this.getValue}
                  className="user-input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Add Comment..."
                  value={this.state.value}
                />
                <button onClick={this.addComment} className="post">
                  Post
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Feed;
```

Comment: `feedList` isn't defined? You didn't import it or initiated it as a state variable.

Comment: @SinanYaman omg My mistake I delete import line for some reason. Even I import the json.file it didn't work I will edit it! Thank you for pointing out though

Comment: If you are importing, `feedList.map` should suffice, `this.feedList` doesn't exist. If you create it like a state variable, it should be accessed `this.state.feedList`

Comment: @SinanYaman Oh yeap! you are right. I got it I missed "state" but feeds still didn't show up :(

Comment: Please edit the question and show how you access the `feedList`. It is still not defined in the question

Comment: @SinanYaman yes you're right. I will do that right away!

Comment: So far, I edit this.feedList --> this.state.feedList because this is a way to access feedlist information what you mentioned

Comment: Now your state doesn't have a feedList field. How do you define feedList?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map it through feedList, but you have't defined it anywhere.
You have commentList, so use that:

```
commentList.map(item =>  console.log(item))
```

Comment: commentList is another one! It adds comment on the feed.